# Parameter 'ViewName' does not match any available view in render view to string asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm using .net6 and I want to render view to string for send an email but I recive an error:
[image]

View addressing is correct, but it can't be render it.

controller(Project.Web/Controllers/AccountController.cs):

```
          string body = _viewRender.RenderToStringAsync("~/Views/Account/Email/EmailBody.cshtml", user);
          SendEmail.Send(register.Email, "Activation email", body);
```

render view to string class(Project.Core/Convertors/RenderViewToString.cs):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace PotLearn.Core.Convertors
{
    public interface IViewRenderService
    {
        string RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model);
    }
    public class RenderViewToString : IViewRenderService
    {
        private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
        private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public RenderViewToString(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
            ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
            _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public  string RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
        {
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);

                if (viewResult.View == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
                }

                var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                };

                var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    viewDictionary,
                    new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                    sw,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions()
                );

                 viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View(Project.Web/Views/Account/Email/EmailBody.cshtml):

```
@model PotLearn.DataLayer.Entities.User.User


<p>@Model.UserName hello!</p>
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because you're using a custom/dummy `ActionContext` without relation to the actual executing one, in combination with the view engines [`FindView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewengines.iviewengine.findview?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method.

That `FindView` method needs information from the execution context.
From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewengines.iviewengine.findview?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

> Finds the view with the given viewName using view locations and information from the context.

---

Since you are passing in an absolute path you can resolve the issue by calling the view engines [`GetView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewengines.iviewengine.getview?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method instead, which does not rely on the execution context.

```
var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.GetView(null, pathToView, false);
```

See the full code below.

---

There's a second issue with your code - although not related to finding the view;
the below call is not being awaited.

```
viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
```

To resolve, you'll need to `await` that one, which requires your method signature to change to return `Task<string>`.

```
public interface IViewRenderService
{
    Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string pathToView, object model);
}
```

The call to render the view will then look like

```
string body = await _viewRender.RenderToStringAsync("~/Views/Account/Email/EmailBody.cshtml", user);
```

---

The full code of the render method

```
public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string pathToView, object model)
{
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.GetView(null, pathToView, false);
        if (viewResult.View == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{pathToView} does not match any available view");
        }

        var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
        {
            Model = model
        };

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(
            actionContext,
            viewResult.View,
            viewDictionary,
            new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
            sw,
            new HtmlHelperOptions()
        );

        await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

        return  sw.ToString();
    }
}
```